# UIImageView uses a lot of memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm creating some kind of image gallery. User can swipe between photo's. (Its just the concept, i know there are good library's out there that can handle this, but it's just to explain the concept).

I'm loading in 3 `UIImageView`, and i'm constantly reusing them. (Lazy loading). Problem is, when i change the image dynamiccaly from one imageview, and keep changing it, the memory is filling up. It's like it does not releases previous attached images. I'm using an array of `UIImages` that I already downloaded from some kind of web service.

As i load my view, i'm allocing and init my `UIImageView`,  then I add it to the view.

```
UIImageView* _imgView;
NSArray* _imgArray;
```

So this array contains `UIImage`

```
-(void)changeImageIndex: (int) i
{
   _imgView.image = [_imgArray objectAtIndex:i];
}
```

if i keep changing the imageindex, memory just gets filled up and filled up.. :s.
My project is ARC enabled.

Somebody has a clue how to solve it?

The image is added (actually changed) by this method:

```
-(void)setCurrentMovie:(GFilm*)film
{

    _currentMovie = nil;
    _currentMovie = film;
    _posterView.image = nil;
    [_youtubeView loadHTMLString:@"" baseURL:nil];
    [_youtubeView stopLoading];
    [_youtubeView setDelegate:nil];

    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
    [_scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:NO];

    CGFloat leftHeight = 0.f;

    _leftView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 110, 205);
    leftHeight += _leftView.frame.size.height;
    _posterView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, _leftView.frame.size.width, _leftView.frame.size.height - 40);

    GImage* img = (GImage*)[_currentMovie.imageList objectAtIndex:0];
    //_posterView.image = img.localImage;
    //@autoreleasepool {


    _posterView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(img.localImage)];



    _btnVertoningen.frame = CGRectMake(0, _posterView.frame.origin.y + _posterView.frame.size.height + 5, _leftView.frame.size.width, 35);

    _posterView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(posterClick)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [_posterView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    [_leftView addSubview:_posterView];

    CGFloat rightHeight = 0.f;
    _rightView.frame = CGRectMake(_leftView.frame.origin.x + _leftView.frame.size.width + 5, _leftView.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width - (_leftView.frame.size.width + _leftView.frame.origin.x) - 15, 1);

    _lblRegie.frame = CGRectMake(0, rightHeight, 48, 16);


    NSMutableString* text = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    NSArray*  arr = _currentMovie.directorList;



    etc.....
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code of how are you populating _imgArray?

Comment: actually, first they are downloaded from a webservice, then they are stored, (with NSCoding protocol), when they are needed, they are loaded. They are all embedded in complex objects.. Per image, the image is downloaded like this: 

_gImage.localImage = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: [[_gFilm.posterUrl stringByAppendingString:_gImage.name] stringByAppendingString:@"&width=390&height=570"]]]];

Comment: i think u are using `imageNamed:` it will save cache of image

Comment: so _imgArray contains a bunch of _gImage objects. I load the imagearray from the "disk", and get the .localImage per _gImage..

Comment: im not using imagenamed :s

Comment: before adding image to `array` set to nil and image view `removefromsuperview` after that add image to `array` and `addsubview` to view then everytime remove and add memory

Comment: how you are adding the image to view, let's us show the code.

Comment: _posterView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(img.localImage)]; <=== this seems to help, instead of _posterView.image = img.localImage but now im browsing a lot slower.. any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your app have memory leak. Try use **imageWithContentsOfFile** instead of **imageNamed**:

```
_imgView.image =  [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
```

Another possibility to have memory leaks with ARC is using a separate thread without an autorelease pool set up. Check this link:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html:

Comment: I am never using imageNamed...

In the parser i get my images like this: _gImage.localImage = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: [[_gFilm.posterUrl stringByAppendingString:_gImage.name] stringByAppendingString:@"&width=390&height=570"]]]];

then, i store my images (using NSCoding), UIImage is a direct property from a complex object.when i need them, i ask them, images are build like this: (NSCoding) self.localImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"localImage"]];